# How to use selector (SEL) with objc_setAssociatedObject?

Tags: objective-c, runtime, associated-object

Can I use somehow parameter of type SEL with objc_setAssociatedObject without converting it to NSString type?

Currently I'm using this code:
`objc_setAssociatedObject(thirdPartyObject, &kSelectorKey, NSStringFromSelector(selector), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);`

Conversion to NSString works, but in feels wrong. There must be more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OBJC_EXPORT void objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, const void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy)`

The 3rd parameter needs to be an object type.  So, yes, you need that conversion.

Comment: underlaying type of SEL is const char*. Technically, it is const void*. But it cannot be retained, because it don't have an ISA.


in iOS 9.2 id defined like `OBJC_EXPORT void objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, const void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy)
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_3_1);`, by the way

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow reacts on some strange way on "Enter" key press. So, seems like you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.
In my example i have passed `indexpath` you have to replace with your para meter

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    yourCustomeCell *aCell;
    NSString *aStrIdentifier = @"yourIdentiFier";
    aCell = (yourCustomeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:aStrIdentifier];

    //you have to set your indexpath
    objc_setAssociatedObject(aCell.btnUpload_or_Add, @"objBtn", indexPath, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    [aCell.YourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonActiontapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return aCell;
}

-(IBAction)yourButtonActiontapped:(UIButton *)sender{

    NSIndexPath *aIndPath =  objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, @"objBtn");
    NSLog(@"row:%@",aIndPath.row);
}
```

> also you have to import `#import <objc/runtime.h>`